# Java Beginner - Polymorphism and Interfaces

Tags: java

Is there any way in Java, to create a child object in it's parents reference type variable and still have access to any implemented interfaces, without either casting to the interface type OR using the interface reference to store the object?

Almost seems like manual polymorphism.

Comment: `still have access to any implemented interfaces` ^_^  ?? Can you demonstrate with small code example ?

Comment: Highly unclear question. Please rephrase your question (if possible with example code) or your question might just get flagged as unclear.

Comment: Polymorphism means that you can use the child objects as replacements for the parent object because they implement the same interface. Obviously the child object's child-specific implemented interfaces won't be visible.

Comment: Okay, Zhuinden answered my question.

What was meant by implemented interfaces was: Interfaces the Child Object implements. They are not accessible when storing the child in a parent type.

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to do this?  If we had an example of what problem you are trying to solve, we may be able to help you solve it without having to jump through such hoops.  In general, passing around a reference to a parent class and then downcasting it to a specific interface that exists only on the child class is usually indicative of a poor design choice somewhere.

Comment: kindly try and post clearer questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though it *is* possible to list all implemented interfaces, I would try to avoid it as much as possible, since it smells like bad design and it certainly isn't a common thing to do.

On the other hand, a very common thing to do is to test if a object is subtype of a certain class / interface. Look at this demo:

```
class Parent { }

interface MyInterface {
    void foo();
}

class Child extends Parent implements MyInterface {
    @Override
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("Foo");
    }
}

void main() throws Exception {
    List<Parent> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Parent());
    list.add(new Child());
    for (Parent p : list) {
        if (p instanceof MyInterface) {
            MyInterface cased = (MyInterface) p;
            cased.foo();
        }
    }
}
```

Here you have a list of `Parent`s, and for all of them that also implement `MyInterface` you can do something special, even call method from `MyInterface` after you have cased your object.

If you truly need to list all interfaces, use [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/):

```
void main() throws Exception {
    List<Parent> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Parent());
    list.add(new Child());
    for (Parent p : list) {
        Class<?>[] interfaces = p.getClass().getInterfaces();
        for (Class<?> i : interfaces) {
            Method firstMethod = i.getMethods()[0];
            firstMethod.invoke(p, new Object[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

This code will look at all interfaces that each `Parent` object in your list implements, and calls first method from each interface on your objects.

However the need for reflextion is very rare (I have used it once in 2 years of programming).

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible or appropriate. We use a reference to the parent class/interface to use the object for some abstract functionality. For example:

```
public interface Command {
    public void execute();
}

public class SomeCode      implements Command { }
public class SomeOtherCode implements Command { }

public class Test {

    public Test {

        List<Command> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add(new SomeCode());
        list.add(new SomeOtherCode());

        runCommands(list);
    }

    public void runCommands(List<Command> list) {
         for (Command c : list)
               list.execute();
    }
}
```

So, we are using the abstract functionality ( execute() ) that is shared amongst Commands. If we want to use a specific method then we logically have to use casting. That is the point of refering to the superclass/interface and also the point in using casting.